# Multiple line items on QB Online Sales Receipt in Zapier

Tags: quickbooks-online, zapier

I need to create multiple line items on a QB Sales Receipt. Zapier has all the fields I need to populate, but I can't seem to make them accept an array.

If I have 3 line items that look like:

Protein - Eggs - $3
Side - Bacon - $4
Side - Sausage - $4

I would expect this to look like:

```
Product/Service: [2,3,3] <---- id's of existing products  
Line Description: ['Eggs','Bacon','Sausage']  
Line Amount: [3,4,4]
```

But this ends up putting everything into the top line of the Sales Receipt for a dollar amount of $344

Comment: Hey there! I'm not quite sure, but if you write into contact@zapier.com our support team will be able to sort you out!

Comment: @xavdid Your support team sent me here